# More about SURF

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, surf

I use the [SURF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speeded_up_robust_features) to match two images. So I don't know when to judge that a picture is similar to another. Can help me, please?

Comment: Some more detail (example pictures of what you are trying to do etc) would be really good

Answer (score 2):

SURF is computer vision Algorithm, it has detector and descriptor it does not tell you if two pictures ar the same or not. The detector detects Interest Points(IP) and the descriptor describes it as an 64 bit long vector. You should run both the Detector algorithm of SURF and the descriptor on both images, and with some matcher algorithm(bruteforce, flann) you can say that the 2 images are similar for X percent. I suggest you to try out ORB or BRIEF but they generate binnary vectors. Some useful article: **[here](http://www.vision.ee.ethz.ch/~surf/eccv06.pdf)**  or ***[here](http://compbio.fmph.uniba.sk/svk2012/svk2012-zbornik.pdf)*** You can find my article called "*Recognition of visual marks on mobile phone*" on pages 225-228

edit:

the output of matcher is a vector of distances between the descriptors. the smaller the distance is the similar the descriptors are.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how much similarity is needed to fit into a category in your classification problem.

In the most basic case you will have an n-dimensional description vector for your image/object. You can then fit this to the vectors of the objects in your training set. Different algorithms are then best for different situations. OpenCV offers different possibilities here. The parameters also depend on the percentage of false positives etc. you are willing to accept.

You have a training set (learning your classificators 'learn' from that) and you have a test set, with which you can control the result of your system.
For more detailed help, one would need to know more about your application, i.e. requirements, example images etc.

Edit: The sample find_obj.cpp does not decide, if the object (box.png) is really found in the scene (box_in_scene.png). It only finds the SURF points in the scene that correspond best to the ones found on the box. That is why there are also wrongly matched point pairs. If you want to make a decision, if the matches count as "found", you can do this for example by setting a maximum average distance (member of the DMatch struct) of the found matches, or by checking if a good transformation matrix can be calculated (e.g. with findHomography). This is shows in the following tutorial: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html#feature-homography I also recommend using the new cpp API of OpenCV and not the rather complicated C API, if possible. It will probably reduce the complexity of your program, making it easier to concentrate on the essential (algorithmic) part of your application. Additionaly as Csabi already said, I also recommended that you have a look at ORB.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but I still can't understand the surf of algorithm of surf,In Opencv,there is an example programme named "find_obj.cpp",Do you know when two pictures are similar,is there a flag I can judge in the  programme  ?

Comment: Hi, I have edited my answer according to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You should check OpenCV's sample file [descriptor_extractor_matcher.cpp](https://github.com/kipr/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/descriptor_extractor_matcher.cpp). You can customize the code by summing up the `filteredMatches.distance` values as a comparison metric. It's distance between descriptors (see [features2d.hpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/features2d/include/opencv2/features2d.hpp)).

Also, if you want to match two images, use HSV histogram comparison. Check [compareHist_Demo.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/Histograms_Matching/compareHist_Demo.cpp)